# How can I preserve DataFrame index names when using to_json in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Right now I have a DataFrame `df2` that looks like this:

```
       Kuwaiti  Non-Kuwaiti   Total
Age                                
0-4     164483       156459  320942
5-9     158377       136935  295312
```

When I do:

```
df2.to_json()
```

I get:

```
'{"Kuwaiti":{"0-4":164483,"5-9":158377},"Non-Kuwaiti":{"0-4":156459,"5-9":136935},"Total":{"0-4":320942,"5-9":295312}}'
```

As you can see, `df2.index.name` is not preserved anywhere.

What can I do to preserve the index name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the `orient` parameter we can pass to `df2.to_json()` will preserve the index name. A solution is to:

1. Re-index the DataFrame so that the index you want to preserve becomes a normal column:

   ```
   df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
   ```

   The DataFrame `df2` is now:

   ```
       Age    Kuwaiti  Non-Kuwaiti   Total
   0   0-4     164483       156459  320942
   1   5-9     158377       136935  295312
   ```
2. Save it as a JSON (ideally with an `orient` that does not preserve the index to save space, `'split'` is the most space efficient).

   ```
   df2.to_json('file.json', orient='split')
   ```
3. Load and re-index.

   ```
   df3 = pd.read_json('file.json', orient='split').set_index('Age')
   ```

   And `df3.index.name` will be as expected:

   ```
          Kuwaiti  Non-Kuwaiti   Total
   Age
   0-4     164483       156459  320942
   5-9     158377       136935  295312
   ```